Derivation of Number of Runs
I'm reading this passage from A First Course in Probability by Ross where it describes how runs are calculated: 
Can someone explain why

is changed to

It seems that losses before the first run and after the last run of wins were optional, but now at least one loss is required for both.

Sorry, I thought I deleted the other one already. I have deleted it now.

No, actually they have done this just to change the variable
Initially, $y_{1}$ & $y_{r+1}$ were $≥0$ and $y_{i}$ was $≥1$ for $i=2,3,...,r$
Either convert them such that all variables become $≥1$. In this way, RHS becomes $m+2$
So you can use the formula of no. of positive integral solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2+...x_r = n$ is $C(n-1,r-1)$
Here, it becomes $C(m+1,r)$
Or you can convert them such that all variables ($Y_i = y_i - 1$ for $i=2,3,...,r$) become $≥0$. In this way RHS becomes $m -(r-1)$
So you can use the formula of no. of non-negative integral solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2+...x_r = n$ is $ C(n+r-1,r-1)$
Here it becomes $C(m-(r-1)+(r+1)-1, (r+1)-1)= C(m+1,r)$
Which are essentially the same

So 1 was added to y_1 and y_(r+1) so that the C(n-1,r-1) formula could be used?

Yes , exactly this reason
